# how to send image as base64 string into android webview current page

Tags: android, webview, base64

My project is a web based app and loaded by android webview. 
I want to call camera by clicking one button on my web page, then catch image back and set back into web page.

Currently I use `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to catch a picture by camera. And then convert the image to **base64** string (`myImgStr`). These steps are fine.

But when I use `webview.LoadUrl("javascript:handleCameraResult('+ myImgStr +')")` to send image string back into web page, there is **null** in web page.

Do you guys know what the issue is and how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: are you testing this on emulator or actual device?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I've got the answer. That is: 
Base64 string received by `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` contains some "\n" which block the entire string inserted through javascript call.

My solution is to remove those "\n" then call wevview.LoadUrl. Everything works well now.